# I keep getting Error in par(op) : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "pin" when I use heatmap in r

Tags: r, heatmap, bioconductor

I'm using R to generate a heatmap for a matrix in R but I keep getting the error "Error in par(op) : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "pin"". here's my code :

```
tentative.normalization<-function(mat,npar){
  if(npar==1){
    return(normalized<-t(apply(m1,1,function(x){x/max(x)})))
 }
 if(npar==2){
   return(normalized<-apply(m1,2,function(x){x/max(x)}))
 }
```

}

```
 mat1.norm.rows<-tentative.normalization(mat1,npar = 1)
 heatmap(mat1.norm.rows)
```